# Swap test to calculate inner product with qiskit for multi-qubit states

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit, circuit-construction

Is it possible to perform a controlled swap test with multiple targets with qiskit? I have tried using cswap(ancilla[0],qb1,qb2), where qb1 is an n-qubit register and qb2 is as well

Comment: It should be possible. In this case you would be swapping `qb1` and `qb2` is `ancilla[0]` is in the 1 state. Is this what you are expecting? Documentation on the `cswap` method can be found here: https://qiskit.org/documentation/api/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.html#qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.cswap

Comment: Yes, this is what I want to happen, but I get the following error message:

qiskit.circuit.exceptions.CircuitError: "Not sure how to combine these qubit arguments:\n [[Qubit(QuantumRegister(3, 'q4'), 0)], [Qubit(QuantumRegister(3, 'q0'), 0), Qubit(QuantumRegister(3, 'q0'), 1), Qubit(QuantumRegister(3, 'q0'), 2)], [Qubit(QuantumRegister(3, 'q2'), 0), Qubit(QuantumRegister(3, 'q2'), 1), Qubit(QuantumRegister(3, 'q2'), 2)]]\n"

Comment: Oh I think the registers need to be the same size. So if `ancilla[0]`,  `qb1`, and `qb2` are a different size then you will get this error. You would need to set multiple `cswap` gates depending on the sizes of qb1 and qb2. For example if `qb1` and `qb2` are of size 2, you would call `cswap(ancilla[0], qb1[0], qb2[0])` and then call `cswap(ancilla[0], qb1[1], qb2[1])`

Comment: @MatthewStypulkoski could you add this as an answer instead of a comment (do not delete the comment)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible, but when calling `cswap`, all of the arguments need to be of the same size. In your example, assuming `ancilla[0]` is 1 qubit, you would need `qb1` and `qb2` to also be 1 qubit. If `qb1` and `qb2` are QuantumRegisters of size > 1, then you would need multiple `cswap` calls. For example, if `qb1` and `qb2` are of size 2:

```
circuit.cswap(ancilla[0], qb1[0], qb2[0])
circuit.cswap(ancilla[0], qb1[1], qb2[1])
```

This way the `ancilla[0]` qubit is still the control for both calls, and all of the arguments in both calls are of the same size.

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't keeping the states that you performed the swap test on, you don't need to use CSWAPs to perform the swap test. You can instead just pair up the qubits from each system, perform Bell basis measurements on them, and count whether you see the 11 result and odd or even number of times.

This:

[image: swap test using cswap]

Gives the same result statistics as this:

[image: swap test using bell measurements]

But the latter is much less demanding on the quantum hardware, because the three qubit gates can be done in the classical postprocessing.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain why the latter works? Also, are the cnots supposed to be before the hadamards?

Comment: @QCQCQC You can rewrite the first circuit into the second by taking advantage of the ability to add or remove operations on qubits that will be discarded. Decompose the CSWAPs into CNOT-TOF-CNOT, the right CNOTs are discarded, introduce Hadamards and measurements, propagate left to flip direction of Toffolis. Yes the CNOTs are where they are supposed to be.