# Is it possible to design a swap test for three qubits? If it is possible how is it different from 2 and 4 qubits? share the design of the swap test?

Tags: qiskit, circuit-construction, quantum-circuit, swap-test

Explain the swap test for 2 qubits to find the distance between qubits. Extend the swap test for 3 and 4 qubits. Will the design differ from each other and share the design for both the swap tests?

Comment: You can carry out swap test for any number of qubits. Just apply the test per each pair of corresponding qubits. If the test is fulfiled for each pair, then states are the same.

Comment: Can you share the quantum circuit for controlled swap test of 3 qubit?

Comment: Please see here https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9775/swap-test-to-calculate-inner-product-with-qiskit-for-multi-qubit-states.   In one answer in the thread you can see swap test for three-qubit state.